# Bootstrap 3 modals: Must I use the modal-header, modal-body and modal-footer tags?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

The following example markup is taken directly from the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see little use for using the `modal-header`, `modal-body` and `modal-footer` div tags. Aside from styling, are there any implications of leaving out these tags and displaying everything inside `modal-content`? For example:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. But there's no padding on modal-content, you can use modal-content and modal-body together or just adjust the css for modal-content.

Comment: Actually, I was thinking of adjusting the CSS for `modal-content`. Something like `padding: 20px;` would do the trick. So regarding the `modal-body`, `modal-header` and `modal-footer` tags... is their sole purpose just for styling?

Comment: Styling. I've been using an addon for the bootstrap modal which helps me accomplish more: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html

Comment: https://github.com/jschr/bootstrap-modal/

Comment: Thank you for the links, they'll be V useful!

Comment: I haven't combined with http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/, but this rocks for images and video (the video is not responsive though, probably fixed with the responsive embed classes or with fitVid.js.

Comment: That lightbox gallery rocks! It's amazing what can be done with modals. Until recently I tried to avoid using them but these days they work so well it's hard to make a case against using them.